# Unable to create a client stubs for a web service

Tags: eclipse, web-services, jax-ws, tomcat7, wsimport

I am trying to learn web service development using JAX-WS.

I am trying out [this](http://java.dzone.com/articles/jax-ws-hello-world) tutorial.

I am able to create and run web service correctly and I got WSDL file when I hit the link `http://localhost:8080/WS/Greeting?wsdl`. However at step 5 of creating client stub using `wsimport` as follows:

```
CD %CLIENT_PROJECT_HOME%\src
wsimport –s . http://localhost:8080/WS/Greeting?wsdl
```

I am getting error as follows:

[image]

Comment: yeah I can hit the WSDL and it shows up the WSDL XML in browser. But problem comes when I try creating client stubs.

Comment: Try doing this: wsimport -keep -verbose http://localhost:8080/WS/Greeting?wsdl

Comment: yess that worked and it created the desired Java classes but unfortunately I didnt understood 1. What was wrong in what I did and 2. What difference it made by your code. Bit noob here too. Please explain in separate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see this are the options and meanings:

> -s: Specifies where to generate the SOURCES
>
> -d: Specifies where to generate the CLASSES
>
> -keep: Says to KEEP the sources
>
> -p: Specifies a package

Now, you were using a "." to specify the source output, that may generate the problem. If your output folder is the current one, specify nothing.

Read [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/wsimport.html) for wsimport documentation and for other tutorial for its usage use [this](http://meow.altervista.org/blog/generare-classi-java-per-invocare-un-web-service-con-wsimport/).

Comment: Do you need any more clarifications?