# Unable to create HelloWorld webservice

Tags: eclipse, web-services, tomcat, ant, jax-ws

I am trying to create a simple HelloWorld webservice using Tomcat, Eclipse, JAX-WS using [this](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/deploy-jax-ws-web-services-on-tomcat/) tutorial.

I created a Dynamic Web Project whose folder hierarchy looks like this.
[image]

I copy pasted the code from the tutorial and ensured that I have put my workspace name appropriately in those Java and XML files

Now I created an Ant builder in eclipse as follows:
[image]

The content of the build.xml is as given in the tutorial.

However when I build the project I get the following error:
[image]

Though in the first image you can see I have explicitly created the `dist` folder under the project directory directly.

**Edit**

Target tab of Ant builder
[image]

Comment: Could you please tell me (or put the screenshot) of the tab Targets of the Edit Configuration of New_Builder

Comment: @luiso1979 uploaded the image of tabs section, check edit to original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ant file replace this:

```
<project name="HelloWorldWS" default="dist" basedir=".">
```

with this

```
<project name="HelloWorldWS" default="war" basedir=".">
```

Note that the last screenshot you posted that it says in Manua Build: `<default target selected>`. So it goes to the build.xml and takes the default defined in the tag `project` and `dist` is not declared inside of it instead `war` is (that at the end does the distribution generation). So use `war` as default.

Comment: sad now `war` file is created, but when deployed on Tomcat and tried to access it at `http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld/hello` as given in tut it gives `404 Requested resource not available`. This webservice thingy is proving hellish to me. I have also tried another simple HelloWorld webservice tut and that approach also stuck and I created another question for it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19114891/unable-to-create-a-client-stubs-for-a-web-service).

Comment: Ok, I assume you copied the web.xml from the tutorial. But did you put the libraries inside the lib folder. Step 5 of the tutorial

Comment: Yess in `tomcatxyz/lib`. It extracted WAR, but still gave 404

Comment: What version of tomcat are you using, try copying the libs in the WEB-INF/lib of your project, just for testing

Comment: My tomcat version 7.0.41. Tried by putting those `WEB-INF/lib` and then rebuilding project - recreating the `WAR` still getting `404` Should I send my WAR? You can open it any archiver.

Comment: Is this tomcat version not compatible?

Comment: If you could send the WAR so I can debug it.

Comment: Anyways, had you tried this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=orctlc_F5Y0 (regarding tomcat 7)

Comment: very bad my organization doesnt allow sharing code to outside, though I told this is HelloWorld web service. And yeah no need to say that chat links and youtube is not working, all blocked x(. Though I will be in touch with you. Please reply then. Really want to know where am going wrong.

Comment: Ok let's see. If you go to browser and type http://localhost:8080 you see the tomcat page or another 404?

Comment: Yeah I could see Tomcat homepage at `localhost:8080`, I did checked that already. Also checked that tomcat is extracting `WAR` creating desired directory hierarchy. And the other question you answered which followed another tut did in fact worked well. I followed next part of that tut and now able to deploy the webservice on Tomcat and created client for it. Both working. But thats different approach - using `wsgen`. But, this `ant` stuff is not working. Anyways thanks to ask to check if Tomcat still working.

Comment: Also this `ant` approach does not use `wsgen`. So, it did not created any extra classes as in case of `wsgen`: `SayHello` and `SayHelloResponse`. We created interface, implementation class, web.xml, and sun-jaxws.xml and then written ant for packaging it all in WAR. Is that approach missing anything?

Comment: The way you are doing it you don't need wsgen (unless you are creating a client). But you should see if it works by going to http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld/hello. There you should the available webmethods of the service.

Comment: Hey sorry for late response. Yess I have checked. Tomcat is running at `localhost:8080`, but `localhost:8080/HelloWorld/hello` gives `404`. [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/8uuzzlcjcqm2s41/7KxcDP-1jn/HelloWorldWS) are my files. `_HelloWorldWS.war` is created by including jax-ws jars in my projects' `WEB-INF/lib`. But it gave exceptions while deploying on tomcat. So I went for removing those JARs from project and included in Tomcats' lib folder. The WAR then created is `HelloWorld.war`. The other 7z file is my dynamic web project in eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Your ant file `build.xml` are missing the `dist` target, try running the `war` target instead.

Comment: I didnt get this as am new to ant, please explain what should be the final content of build.xml

Comment: Actually that error I got when I selected project in Project Explorer and then selected `Project|Build Project` from eclipse menu bar. Am I missing anything here. Can we selectively run targets here. I may sound absolutely stupid, but please help. Am noob with respect to Ant.

Comment: You can run it as @Luiso1979 explain in his answer, or you can right click the build file and choose run as, and select the war target.